# vue.js how to address warning "<transition> can only be used on a single element. "

Tags: vue.js

I'm using a transition for a component I created that repeats multiple times on the rendered view:

```
<slide-y-down-transition>
    <div
      v-for="comment in comment.comments"
      :key="comment.id"
      v-show="displayComments"
    >
      <CommentCard
      />
    </div>
</slide-y-down-transition>
```

But when I test the view it provides a console warning:

```
[Vue warn]: <transition> can only be used on a single element. Use <transition-group> for lists.
```

So I researched it and found that the documentation recommends using 'group'.  This is a third party package called "vue2-transitions" with a group prop, so I tried out:

```
<slide-y-down-transition group>
    <div
      v-for="comment in comment.comments"
      :key="comment.id"
      v-show="displayComments"
    >
      <CommentCard
      />
    </div>
</slide-y-down-transition>
```

This eliminated the warning, but resulted in unexpected behavior; instead of pushing the rest of the view's content down as the section is expanded or contracted, it seems to do a 'v-show' without first pushing down the rest of the view's content.  As a result, the view's bottom content is overlayed with the newly-revealed CommentCard.  It looks atrocious:

[image]

I don't want to alter the 3rd party package ("vue2-transitions") if I can help it.  I'm sure if an original creator of the package can comment, it would clear things up.

So I'm now just investigating how I can continue to use the normal transition without the 'group'?  It works fine, but I'm concerned about the Vue warning.

**My Question:** What causes this Vue warning, and is there any way to address it without resorting to using a 'group' transition?

**Other (Possibly) Important Info:** The CommentCard is recursive.

In other words, the comment list can contain multiple CommentCards as shown, and each of *those* CommentCards can contain its own list of CommentCards.  The idea is for the transition to display (or NOT display) those child lists of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate this error, I ended up with the following code in my CommentCard component:

```
<template>
  <slide-y-down-transition>
     // MORE CODE HERE
          <slide-y-down-transition>
            <div v-show="displayComments">
              <div v-for="comment in comment.comments" :key="comment.id">
                <CommentCard
                  :comment="comment"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </slide-y-down-transition>

  </slide-y-down-transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CommentCard",

  // MORE CODE HERE
}
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

The key for me was the recursive behavior.  To keep the vertical collapse-expand transition working, I needed to add the transition to each individual CommentCard's *overall* template, and then within each CommentCard, place a transition on each one's individual 'child list' of comments.

Works perfect with no Vue warnings now.

What I learned is that the group option is necessary on list items to handle each transition separately within a group context.

However.... if you **wrap an overall list item in a single div tag**, you can appropriately move the v-show out of the list and into that single enclosing div tag like so:

```
 <div v-show="displayComments">
```

That way, Vue.js will consider the v-show to be for 'one' element and it will treat the transition as collapsing or expanding that entire div, which includes all the sub elements.

Since I wanted the **whole** child group to be expanded or contracted, that works fine in my case; however, if you do need finer-grained control over visibility or transition of individual child elements, you'll need to look further than what I did.

Answer (score 2):

`<transition>` is for:

- Individual nodes
- Multiple nodes where only 1 is rendered at a time

For simultaneously rendered elements you need to use `<transition-group>` and give keys to each element.

You can read more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions).

Comment: As for the third party package you're using, it'd be helpful if you included the name of the package

Comment: Added it to the original question.  It is "vue2-transitions".

Comment: "and give keys to each element...."  I thought I'd done that with :key="comment.id"

Comment: Thank you @Interog. Hmm, not sure why it wouldn't be working then. Could you post a gif of the problem? Or better yet, a snippet?

Comment: With `<transition-group>`, Vue does replace it with a `<span>`. Do you have any CSS which is targeting a span? Maybe with `position: absolute`?

Comment: Good guess - and yeah, I saw that in the docs as well.  But no; nothing that is scoped to override or otherwise alter the span tag.

Comment: "Elements inside group transitions should have display: inline-block or must be placed in a flex context..." Have you tried this?

Comment: I'll take a look at it ... I think you're on the right track looking at how Vue.js treats the *group* transition differently on the dom.  BTW I edited the question to include a small pic of the rendered behavior when I currently use the 'group' prop.